# mySQL user defined function for if record exists

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I am looking for something along the lines of a simple user defined function in mysql which returns true or false depending on if the record is found. What I am struggling is the syntax
Any MySQL punters who can point me in right direction...

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `doesItExist`(`id` int) RETURNS bool
BEGIN
  declare var_name bool;
  IF (EXISTS (select 1 into var_name 
  from table_name 
  where id = id;))
  return var_name;
END$$
```

Comment: `where id = id`? How do you suppose that MySQL should understand than one `id` is the column and the other is the parameter?

Comment: @ypercube the right hand id refers to the parameter passed in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the point of having a such function, this should work:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `IS_RECORD_EXISTS`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `IS_RECORD_EXISTS`(`FIELD_VALUE` INT) RETURNS bool
BEGIN
  DECLARE flag bool DEFAULT false;

  SELECT  EXISTS(
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    `City`
  WHERE 
    `id` = FIELD_VALUE) INTO flag;
  RETURN flag;
END$$
```

Comment: I am using a self join and hence I need it to check if the field exists in the second alias table.e.g table one self join table 2, IF_RECORD_EXISTS(table2.id) in select. Hope this makes sense